# Installing Larch by anaconda python

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to install larch by using `conda install -c conda-forge larch` in Python, but it takes a long time over 8 hours and it is still running. [anaconda pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoRJs.png).

How can I install larch by using conda? How to solve for a long-running installation?

Answer (score 1):

The conflict reporting implies that it is incompatible with the environment you are attempting to install into. Instead, create a new environment:

```bash
## 'foo' is arbitrary - choose a meaningful name
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge larch
```